# List repositories for use Red Hat 7.3

Tags: centos, redhat

I installed red hat server-7.3 for x64.
Now need to install others packeges.
But yum not working, because not add repositories.

Try to use information from this url
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel5-fedora-core-add-new-yum-repository.html

But url not working and OS back error - curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foo.nixcraft.com;

Please help me with url for use dowload packeges from Internet for OS  red hat server-7.3

Comment: Following a nine year old RHEL **5** manual on RHEL **7** won't work.

Comment: Trying to use an example yum repo as if it were literally real won't work either. Unfortunately that web page is not very well written, and it may not be clear to non-native English speakers that it is an example, rather than an actual yum repository.

Comment: I can to use this REPO - http://download3.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/7/?

Comment: The best way to install EPEL is by simply installing the EPEL rpm package https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

Comment: finded information about free Repositories on this URL http://tecadmin.net/top-5-yum-repositories-for-centos-rhel-systems/#
try to install 
 rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-rpm-macros-7-8.noarch.rpm
 
but OS back error

Loading http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-rpm-macros-7-8.noarch.rpm
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: skipping http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-rpm-macros-7-8.noarch.rpm - transfer failed

URL - working, Access to Internet from server exist.
Where may be problem?

Comment: On web repo exist New version EPEL rpm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you actually installed Red Hat Enterprise Linux you both need a valid RHEL support contract/subscription and you need to [activate it](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273) for instance with:

```
# subscription-manager register --username <username> --password <password> --auto-attach
```

or similar. Then you'll be able to install Red Hat supported packages with yum. Please be aware that a separate yum module is used to access RHN and content depends on your subscriptions rather than repo config files.

The error message seems to indicate a more basic problem though:

> Could not resolve host: foo.nixcraft.com;

indicates a DNS problem (check your `/etc/resolv.conf`) or a wider networking issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Red Hat 7 you can use EPEL

rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm

variant to use Repositories for CentOS

http://cutler.io/2012/07/installing-centos-packages-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux/